# .net HttpCookie class / session cookie questions

Tags: .net, session, cookies, session-state

I am interested on how to make a regular `HttpCookie` object into a cookie that expires at the end of a session. I am not interested in someone `showing me HttpContext.Session`. How does a session cookie look in the response headers compared to a normal cookie? How can I modify a `HttpCookie` to expire at the end of a session? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A session cookie is just a cookie that doesn't have any expiration date set.

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("name", "value"));
```

or:

```
Response.Cookies["name"] = "value";
```

Answer (score 7):

A cookie with an expiration of DateTime.MinValue (1/1/0001) will expire at the end of the session. This is the default expiration date for a cookie in asp.net.

You can force a cookie to be deleted off the client imediately by setting the expiration date to something before "now" (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d)) in which case it will be deleted when it hits the client.

If we had nullable types back when HttpCookie was coded my guess is that a null date would equate to a session based cookie and anything else would translate into the expiration value but this is not the case.

Comment: It looks like not setting an expiration (in the response headers) has the same effect?

Comment: I haven't tested that so I can't say for sure. Just recently spent a lot of time dealing with a cookie library for our project framework. Personally I prefer fruit these days.

Answer (score 5):

Expiration of cookie:

- Session cookie - Expires date should be DateTime.MinValue which is 1/1/0001 00:00:00
- Normal cookie (Time limited) - Expires date is any future date equal or more than the current DateTime.Now.
- Deleted cookie - anytime between DateTime.MinValue and DateTime.Now.

To change the cookie into session cookie, simply assign MinValue.

```
httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;
```

If your cookie is new one. The default value for DateTime should be DateTime.MinValue and no need to set.

CallMeLaNN